# poisson distribution, and difference between homogeneous and non-homogenous ones

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Can anyone explain poisson distribution in an easy way to understand and the differences between homogeneous and non-homogeneous ones?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the Poisson distribution, or are you talking about Poisson processes? I don't understand what (in)homogeneity would mean in the former case.

Comment: I've meant poisson distribution.

Comment: I'd say the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is most easily understood by thinking about the binomial distribution with $n$ going to infinity and $p=\lambda/n$. That is assuming you don't want to talk about the connection to Poisson processes (which is interesting in and of itself).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are refering to Poisson process.

Imagine a restaurant, the customers arrive randomly in. If you modelise the time occurence of their arrival by a homogeneous Poisson process on let's say $(00h,24h)$, you mean that the customers can arrive at any time with the same probability. Nonetheless, it is more realistic to use an inhomogeneous PP in order to capture the fact that there are many more clients in $(12h,14h)$ and $(20h,22h)$ let's say.

Comment: I refer to poisson distribution.

Comment: What is your definition of a non homogeneous Poisson distribution ?